# Remove hash from URL (lightbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I know there's a lot of questions about my problem, but I can't find any solution.

I have a lightbox, every pictures has got a specific ID with hash (#picture-1, #picture-2, ...)

I want to remove hash from URL :

*gallery.php/#picture*

to
*gallery.php/picture*

Script :

```
$(location).attr("hash","value"));
```

I find something to remove the hash but it broke my lightbox (redirect to 404 error)

```
$(location).attr("href","value"));
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Which lightbox plugin is it? Most likely it has a `history`  (or something similar)property that if you turn it of there will be no hash at the URL

Comment: From which URL do you want to remove the hash?  The window, or some links on the page?  More code would be helpful here.

Comment: @TasosK. I can't find this line of code, I'm looking for it, I will edit my question if I find it. Here's the documentation of iLightbox http://ilightbox.net/documentation.html

Comment: @TasosK. There are too much lines on the script so I created a fiddle where there are the script and the main lines of this script in "HTML" that can be useful. Maybe it can help. http://fiddle.jshell.net/bbutww4s/1/

Comment: In the demo page, the example using deeplinking and infinite are changing the hash. Try set either of those properties to `false` and see If that fix is it

Answer (score 0):

you need a javascript or php routing, javascript frameworks as angularjs has a route module (codeigniter for php has one too). You need to prevent location href behavior.

When you change the location gallery.php/#picture (hash changing event fired) but gallery.php/picture tries to redirect picture directory.